# Image in R Leaflet marker popups

Tags: r, leaflet, rstudio

I'm trying to make my leaflet map generated by R include images in the popups for markers in a dynamic way - e.g.,

```
library(leaflet)


pts <- data.frame(Latitude = 30, Longitude = 30, file = "thing")

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data = pts, lng =~Longitude, lat = ~Latitude,
                   popup =~ paste0("<img src = './", file, ".jpg'>"))
```

The above generates an bad image (ye olde ? in an image), however. Viewing source makes it look like it *should* work....not sure what's wrong here.

```
{"lineCap":null,"lineJoin":null,"clickable":true,"pointerEvents":null,
"className":"","stroke":true,"color":"#03F","weight":5,"opacity":0.5,"fill":true,"
fillColor":"#03F","fillOpacity":0.2,"dashArray":null},null,null,
"<img src = './thing.jpg'>"]}],"limits":{"lat":[30,30],"lng":[30,30]}},"evals":[]}
```

Comment: what about: tags$div(
  HTML('<a src="/PathToYourFile/YourFile.png" width="400" height="400"> </a>'))

Comment: Nope, that just made the popup R generated have a lot of extra odd tag text.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you can use `svg` instead of `jpg` it should work. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352539/plotting-barchart-in-popup-using-leaflet-library/36237460#36237460).

**EDIT/UPDATE:**
It is possible to embed image files that are not local. Consider the following, where we add the R logo from Wikipedia.

```
library(leaflet)

pts <- data.frame(Latitude = 30, Longitude = 30, file = "thing")

file <- 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c1/Rlogo.png/274px-Rlogo.png'

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data = pts, lng =~Longitude, lat = ~Latitude,
                   popup = paste0("<img src = ", file, ">"))
```

This works just fine.

For local files it is a bit more tricky as `leaflet`, or better the underlying `htmltools`, is expecting relative paths to the specified image file from the location of the `index.html` which is being stored in a temporary folder that is being created on widget creation. Hence we cannot know in advance where to save our images beforehand. [@Spacedman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336235/how-to-access-map-generated-by-leaflet-in-r) provided some functions for storing `leaflet` maps in a user specified folder, so we can use those to create our working map like this

```
library (leaflet)

saveas <- function(map, file){
  class(map) <- c("saveas",class(map))
  attr(map,"filesave")=file
  map
}

print.saveas <- function(x, ...){
  class(x) = class(x)[class(x)!="saveas"]
  htmltools::save_html(x, file=attr(x,"filesave"))
}

file <- '/path/to/folder/image.png'

pts <- data.frame(Latitude = 30, Longitude = 30, file = "thing")

m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data = pts, lng =~Longitude, lat = ~Latitude,
                   popup = paste0("<img src = ", file, ">"))

saveas(m, "/path/to/folder/index.html")
```

We save the `index.html` in the same folder as the `png` so now if we open the `index.html` in a browser the popup should render the `png` just fine. This should also work with `jpg` files.

Note that this will still not show the desired popup behaviour in the RStudio viewer. There may be a possible workaround for this also by encoding the images to base64. I will dig deeper into this when I find the time.

**UPDATE 2:** 
The development version of **mapview** now has dedicated functions for this:

- `popupImage()` for embedding local or remote images
- `popupGraph()` for embedding **lattice**, **ggplot2** or **htmlwidgets** based plots

The development version of **mapview** can be installed with:

```
devtools::install_github("environmentalinformatics-marburg/mapview", ref = "develop"
```

Comment: Hrm - nope, it's jpgs supplied by a collaborator.

Comment: Seems this is an OS-related issue. On my machine, the approach suggested by @TimSalabim works perfectly on Ubuntu 14.04, but fails on Windows 7.

Comment: Ha - I think I'll just upload them to another server. Seems like the better solution for the moment. Or at least, easier!

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add to the above discussion that you have to double quote the path in order for it to work with local sources (i.e., "'/path/to/folder/image.png'")

Comment: If this doesn't directly answer the question, please consider leaving a comment to the TOs question instead.

Comment: I'd love to, but i need 50 rep to comment.