# How to resize large images in R Leaflet marker popups?

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

My code:

```
library(leaflet)

df   <- as.data.frame(read.csv("arts.csv"))
file <- as.character(df$url)

leaflet() %>% addTiles() 
          %>% addMarkers(data = df, lng = ~lon, lat = ~lat, 
                         popup = paste0("<img src = ", file, ">")) 
          %>% popupOptions(maxWidth = "auto")
```

I used some code snippet from here: [Image in R Leaflet marker popups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36433899/image-in-r-leaflet-marker-popups)

My question is: how can I easily resize large images appearing in popups?

The illustartion of the problem:
[image: For Example, I would like to make this photo of Cave Rapa Nui smaller to fit the pop-up.]

For Example, I would like to make this photo of Cave Rapa Nui smaller to fit the pop-up.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adjust the size by using the HTML `width` attribute.

Edit your code from above to e.g.

```r
map <- leaflet() %>% 
           addTiles() %>%
           addMarkers(data = df,
                      lng = ~lon,
                      lat = ~lat,
                      popup = paste0("<img src = ", file, " width = 300>"))

map  # print the map
```

[image]

Comment: Vielen Dank @help-info.de!